# Переопределение кнопки submit

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Есть форма на bootstrap c кнопкой submit, так вот мне нужно переопределить запрос который отправляется по нажатию на эту кнопку. Но чтобы осталась вся логика работы кнопки submit. То есть проверка на заполненность обязательных полей. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form name="contact_form" method="post" action="dumb.htm" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
<h1>Пожалуйста введите Ваше имя.</h1>
<p>Ваше имя: <input type="text" name="contact_name"></p>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Отправить данные"></p>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate_form ( )
{
valid = true;
    if ( document.contact_form.contact_name.value == "" )
    {
            alert ( "Пожалуйста заполните поле 'Ваше имя'." );
            valid = false;
    }
    return valid;
 }
 </script>
```

Также тэг form содержит onsubmit атрибут для вызова JavaScript функции проверки validate_form (), когда нажимается кнопка "Отправить данные".

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле можно повесить любой обработчик на кнопку submit или на саму форму, главное НЕ вставляет следующую строчку

`e.preventDefault();`

где e - параметр эвента при обработке события submit. Данная строка отменяет стандартное действие на submit событие (обычно это отправка формы) и выполнять кастомные действия. Валидация полей обычно как раз таки так и делает ( 'form.validate' из jQuery).

Т.е.

```
 jQuery("#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // это отменяет! действие базового submit
    // do something
    return false; //чтобы форма не отправилась, и true для отправки
 });
```

Обработчиков на submit может быть сколько угодно, просто последовательность их вызова будет в том порядке, в котором они объявлены.